# When an I/O operation is being done in a synchronous method, does it always spawn a new thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, io, synchronous

The following [read](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/io-threads-explained/) claims that when we're in a method A, and we for example read a stream to its end, the read operation will spawn an I/O thread, while the main thread will be waiting on that to complete.

Is that really the case? Why wouldn't the main thread do all that work, instead of waiting on something else to do it? Isn't that the main idea of what "[there is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)" is all about?

Comment: A thread is a process and the Net library can create a process without it being in parallel.  A synchronous method blocks which means it wait until complete while asynchronous can doing other processing while an operation is waiting to complete.  So the best way of looking at what is being do (instead of using thread) is determine what operations are being done in parallel and which are blocking and which are non blocking.

Comment: @jdweng Could you please check out the following code snippet - https://pastebin.com/bAmhKf2F and let me know if what is claimed in the comment true?

Comment: The section related to the I/O threads the article is totally misleading and doesn't correspond to reality. So called I/O thread isn't a special thread - it's the same regular thread (typically from a thread pool) with binding to a I/O completion port and such thread is triggered upon on I/O completion, not earlier like the article states.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov so it is as I've thought to be - the thread that's in this method (https://pastebin.com/bAmhKf2F) will do the I/O work and wait on it to complete. There is no second thread involved. Correct?

Comment: This method is totally different story - it doesn't involve an I/O thread at all and the thread which initiated the I/O requests is waiting for it's completion - that's synchronous flow and has nothing to do with I/O asynchrony.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov thank you! feel free to post an answer if there isn't already a duplicate on this

Comment: The [article](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/io-threads-explained/) uses the term "I/O thread" as a synonym to "request to device", in an attempt to explain the concept of asynchronous programming and its difference from parallel programming. It seems that the attempt failed to promote understanding, and promoted confusion instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since .NET asynchronous I/O has arisen initially in environment of Windows OS the given considerations are based on the Windows-based I/O concepts.

To start with, there are two types of the I/O flows: synchronous and asynchronous. The former is based on the waiting mechanism which implies that a thread which initiated an I/O operation at some point (typically when request hits a driver) is put into the waiting state by the OS scheduler and is awaken back by the scheduler when the I/O operation completes. The latter is based on specific notification mechanism which implies that after sending an I/O request the thread keeps doing other things and the I/O completion notification is sent separately to this or any other thread depending on the internal threads configuration.

Now as for the I/O threads - the I/O notification mechanism in Windows systems is implemented by using so-called I/O completion ports (IOCP). Briefly an application can create a completion port (you can think of it as a queue) which can be associated with more than one file handle and any thread can be associated to the completion port when it calls specific API on this port for the first time. That way the scheduler keeps the associations between the completion ports and threads which are associated with them to handle I/O completions more efficiently. Briefly a thread which is associated with completion port is put into waiting state and is awaken when the status of completion request is updated. For the .NET world the infrastructure creates the pools of such threads and they are denoted as I/O threads.

The example given in the article implies using synchronous I/O flow with waiting by the initial thread for the I/O operation completion. In contrast an asynchronous I/O scenario from the .NET perspective means using an additional thread for the I/O completion handling (but not earlier than completion occurs).